# PHP MySQL Query Get Category Name From Multiple ID Array

Tags: php, mysql

I have category table `tb_category`

```
categoryid | category_name
1          | New Product
2          | Promo
```

And I have product table `tb_product`

```
productid | product_name | categoryid_fk
1         | Watch        | 1
2         | Bag          | 1,2
```

And now I want to get category name from `productid` = 2 with `categoryid_fk` = 1,2

How to do that?

My SQL code so far:

```
//category id --> 1,2
$qCategory = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM tb_category WHERE categoryid IN ('" . $dProduct['categoryid_fk'] . "')");
foreach($qCategory as $cause)
{
    echo $cause['category_name'];
}
```

When I run the query I only get the category name with single `categoryid`.

Comment: You need to join the tb_product-table to your query

Comment: @Bernhard Do you have an example?

Comment: You need to normalize, create `tb_prod_cat` to join these tables on `productid` and `categoryid` and would have 3 rows: `1 | 1` - `2 | 1` and `2 | 2`. Then join `tb_product` > `tb_prod_cat` > `tb_category`.

Comment: Is categoryid_fk defined as a set or varchar? please tell us how tb_product was created

Comment: Hi anonymxmous, categoryid_fk is varchar.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: @tadman OK noted. I got your word. (y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use find_in_set function. Usage: find_in_set(search_string, list of strings). 
See demo here:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4e5a48/1

EDIT: since the requirement is changed, add a replace function to remove spaces so that find_in_set will work.

```
SELECT tb_category.*  
FROM tb_category,tb_product 
WHERE find_in_set(categoryid, replace(categoryid_fk,' ','')) > 0
and productid = 2;

Result:
categoryid  category_name
1           New Product
2           Promo
```

Comment: Tried your code, but it only show me only 1 category

Comment: did you copy and paste my code? it is working well in sqlfiddle and the result is at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Yes, just now tried. I still only got 1 category. Could you please share your sqlfiddle?

Comment: I updated my answer to put sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4e5a48/1

Comment: Just now tried, I got the problem. `(2,'Bag','1,2')`. When I set like this `(2,'Bag','1, 2')` <-- with space after `1`. Is it possible? I need to set it using space.

Comment: no. Find_in_set works only if it is delimited by a comma. I will see what I can do.